# Sometimes push notification not working

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have followed all procedure described by apple to crete push notification.It is working fine.Sometimes it is not working.

Comment: What happens when it works fine ?

Comment: are you developing in different computer? dont forget to import the app certificate, developer/product..without this, it wont work. i say this cuz sometimes i develop in a different computer and forget to import the app certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the notification payload sent size by the server is less or equal to 256 bytes. Nothing can guarantee the delivery of a push notification but ensuring that your json respects this rule would help. Also, you could check [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12/#Sending_our_first_push_notification).